# Customize ComboBox in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a form in Microsoft Access that has 2 ComboBoxes.  The first ComboBox is populated with a SQL query that accesses a list of values from a table.  The 2nd ComboBox is will also be populated with a SQL query, but the 2nd ComboBox SQL query takes a parameter.  I want to use the text that is currently in the 1st ComboBox as the parameter into the SQL query which is the back-end of the 2nd ComboBox.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this: [Basing one combo box on another](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access/HA011730581033.aspx)